# How can I transform a Discriminate Union into a DU where each Case is an Array of the Initial DU cases

Tags: typescript

is it possible to transform this DU using mappend/conditional types

```
type MyDU =
| {kind: 'foo'}
| {kind: 'bar'}

type Transformed = DU2Array<MyDU>
```

such that we get the folllowing result

```
type Transformed =
| {kind: 'foo'}[]
| {kind: 'bar'}[]
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. that was easier than I thought

```
type DU2Array<T> = T extends {} ? T[] : never
```